# Python graph from excel data - Change x interval , but data got from excel

Tags: python, excel, database, dataframe, matplotlib

ı have data in Excel. and this data contains information up to 1996-2010, you can check [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMSou.png) you can see a few data.(there are 68000 data in total). But when ı try to plot it 1996-1998-2000....2010 is written on the x-axis.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYIvV.png) I want it to write all the years 1996-1997-1998-1999- ... 2009-2010. Can you help please? Here my code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df=pd.read_excel("Julian_iski_data_python.xlsx")

b2_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "B2" ) ]
k0_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "K0" ) ]
m8_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "M8" ) ]
m14_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "M14" ) ]
m23_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "M23" ) ]
my2_station= df[ ( df["prSM [db]"] == 1) & ( df["Station"] == "MY2" ) ]

b2_years= b2_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
b2_temperature= b2_station["T(degC)"]

k0_years= k0_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
k0_temperature= k0_station["T(degC)"]

m8_years = m8_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
m8_temperature= m8_station["T(degC)"]

m14_years = m14_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
m14_temperature= m14_station["T(degC)"]

m23_years = m23_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
m23_temperature= m23_station["T(degC)"]

my2_years = my2_station["yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss"]
my2_temperature= my2_station["T(degC)"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axes = fig.add_axes([0.04,0.06,0.95,0.91])


axes.plot(b2_years,b2_temperature,"ro",label="B2")
axes.plot(k0_years,k0_temperature,"b^",label="K0")
axes.plot(m8_years,m8_temperature,"gs",label="M8")
axes.plot(m23_years,m23_temperature,"md",label="M23")
axes.plot(my2_years,my2_temperature,"c*",label="MY2")


axes.set_xlabel("Time")
axes.set_ylabel("Temperature")
axes.legend()

axes.xaxis.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as md


df=pd.read_excel("Julian_iski_data_python.xlsx")

df = df[["prSM [db]", "Station", "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss", "T(degC)"]]
df = df.loc[df["prSM [db]"] == 1]
df = df.loc[df["Station"].isin(["B2", "K0", "M8", "M14", "M23", "MY2"])]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
axes = fig.add_axes([0.04,0.06,0.95,0.91])
sns.lineplot(data=df, x="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss", y="T(degC)", hue="Station")
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(1,month=1,day=1))
```

see [examples of style](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html)

Comment: matplotlib works with numpy arrays (a retrograde package). Seaborn can work with pandas DataFrames. It makes everything easier and "ggplot-like".

Comment: Thank you sir , but ı have one problem still. X values are still 1996 - 1998- 2000 ..-2010. 
How can I show all years?

Comment: And last question is , what does this row do ? df = df.loc[df["Station"].isin(["B2", "K0", "M8", "M14", "M23", "MY2"])] ... I deleted this one and the graph was same. I want to get only B2 and K0 station but when ı try to df = df.loc[df["Station"] == "B2" & df["Station"] == "K0" ] , ı get error .. How can ı take only B2 and K0 station... I will be appreciate if you answer sir.

Comment: `df = df.loc[df["Station"].isin(["B2", "K0", "M8", "M14", "M23", "MY2"])]` filters the dataset for these 6 stations. If there are only six of then in the original dataset, and you want only B2 and K0, you may want to change this line to `df = df.loc[df["Station"].isin(["B2", "K0"])]`

Comment: `df = df.loc[df["Station"] == "B2" & df["Station"] == "K0" ]` may start to work if you change it to `df = df.loc[(df["Station"] == "B2") & (df["Station"] == "K0" )]`

Comment: For the years on the x axis, I corrected my code in the response above to reflect that.

Comment: You are welcome. It seems I missed a couple of things in the added code above. Made some corrections.

Comment: When ı change the month as 12 , why does nothing change? ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1,month=1,day=1)) , what does month=1 and day=1 mean?

Comment: I suppose that in `axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(base=1,month=1,day=1))`  the parameters `month` and `day` locate the tick on exactly that day of each year. If they are 1 and 1 then the tick sits on January 1. So you are free to move it (but it doesn't make much sense unless one lives in a country where the year starts on a different day).

Comment: Hmm ty. This is the really my last question. I checked it but ı didnt find it. If you look at my code in the question, I colored all the stations one by one and only marked them with a marker. like --> axes.plot(k0_years,k0_temperature,"b^",label="K0") .. Do you have any idea how can ı do this on the new code.

Comment: I used style= .. and it works , ı think ı did it. sns.scatterplot(data=df, x="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.sss", y="T(degC)", hue="Station",style="Station")